# How to iterate over each object in array one by one not simultaneously in JS?

Tags: javascript

What i want to achieve:
A function that iterates over an array and calls other functions one by one, waits until function is complete before calling another

Every time the function is called it should go back to the start of the array
e.g `1, 2, 3, 4` if `5` is added, it should call functions that start from `1` before reaching `5`

Here is what i have tried after some searching:

```
function startFlash(num, value) {
console.log(num);
if (0 < num.length) {
    console.log('settimeup');
    setTimeout(function () {
        sequence.forEach(function (entry) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                if (entry == "red") {
                    flashRed();
                } else if (entry == "green") {
                    flashGreen();
                } else if (entry == "blue") {
                    flashBlue();
                } else if (entry == "yellow") {
                    flashYellow();
                }
            }, 1000)
        })
        num++;
        startFlash(num, value);
    }, 1000);
}

}
```

So `startFlash` is being called by a function which uses `math.floor` to generate a number between 1-4 and depending on the number, adds the color, red/blue/yellow/green to the array `sequence`

Now the code above calls all method at the same time which is not what i want.

Heres something else i've tried after doing more searches:

```
if (sequence[sequence.length -1] == "red") {
            flashRed();
         } else if (sequence[sequence.length -1] == "green") {
            flashGreen();           
         } else if (sequence[sequence.length -1] == "blue") {
            flashBlue();
         } else if (sequence[sequence.length -1] == "yellow") {
            flashYellow();          
         }
```

Now this code above only calls the latest value in the array like it suggests, but i need it to start from the first value in the array

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

```
let chain = Promise.resolve();
sequence.forEach(entry=>{
    chain = chain.then(()=>{
        if (entry == "red") flashRed()
        // ... etc
    })
})
```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: sequence.foreach is not a function

Comment: That should be `forEach`, sorry. Corrected now.

Comment: Sorry, this executes all the methods at the same time, not one by one